# Python 3.4 spyder2: programmatic script for %clear

Tags: python, spyder

I know that I can type %clear into the console itself, but is there a way to program %clear functionality into a script so as to allow better console flow for prompts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.system` to send commands to the shell; `'cls'` will clear the screen in Windows. See: [before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqvQT.png) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njzjv.png).

(If you're not using it in the interactive console, the `0` return value will just be thrown away.)

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) @marcus-sherman Just to be clear, this option only works on Windows. It doesn't work on Linux or Mac, I don't know why.